# async await not working if sendgrid failed to sent email

Tags: node.js

I have a question.
I am trying to sent the user a email when they have created an account.

But when Sendgrid fails to sent the email the async await function didn't notice that and the code runs further.

This is my email module

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
 
   module.exports = {
        FreshleafVerificationEmail: async(receiver) => {
            const msg = {
                to: receiver,
                from: 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
                subject: 'Verifieer uw email adres - FreshLeaf',
                text: 'Verifieer uw email adres door te klikken op de onderstaande link'
            }
            await sgMail
            .send(msg)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response[0].statusCode)
              console.log(response[0].headers)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }
    }
```

And this is where the method gets executed

```
    try {
        //Save settings and user in the database
        await FreshleafVerificationEmail(newUser.email)
        await newSetting.save();
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json({message: 'Er is een nieuwe gebruiker aangemaakt', user: user})
    } 
    catch(error) {
        res.status(400).json({message: 'Er is een probleem opgetreden', error: error})
    }
```

Can someone help me with this problem

Comment: Email is inherently a store-and-forward system. There are quite a few failure modes, like undeliverable email, that you simply cannot detect from the sending API. Sendgrid offers other APIs you can use, several minutes after sending messages, to determine whether messages bounced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `catch` is handling the error condition and allows the code to continue. If you want other error handlers to see the error then it needs to `throw` again:

```
        FreshleafVerificationEmail: async(receiver) => {
            const msg = {
                to: receiver,
                from: 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
                subject: 'Verifieer uw email adres - FreshLeaf',
                text: 'Verifieer uw email adres door te klikken op de onderstaande link'
            }
            try {
                const response = await sgMail.send(msg)
                console.log('Email sent', response[0].statusCode, response[0].headers)
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log('Email failed to send', msg, error)
                throw error
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solution covers the situation when Sendgrid does not accept the email, it does not and cannot handle the situations when Sendgrid cannot send the email. See the note of @O.Jones on the qestion.

Comment: @matt Thanks, throw error did the trick and resolves my issue

Comment: The try catch worked for me when I had an intermittent SSL connectivity error. It is very frustrating to debug as this promise dies silently when there is no resolve.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29355

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the answer by @Matt covers the error situation when Sendgrid does not accept the email. As @O.Jones does suggest, the API would be the way to go. I do not work with this particular library, but Sendgrid should return a uniq ID of the email if it was accepted. That can be used to search for the status of the email via API.

Sendgrid provides multiple statuses:
https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed
You should look for `Delivered` or in case of `Deferred` you should wait more.

I assume that this may be a bad news, but Sendgrid copies hear a behavior of any other standard email server. With a simpler interface.